# Is the German (DE) version of Dishonored low-violence / censored?

Tags: version-differences, dishonored

I just got a copy of Dishonored (DE) on Steam.  The German (DE) version of Dishonored can be unlocked from any country; however, is it any different from the version bought in other countries?

For other games, such as [Saints Row 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ocu8JqD7EEk), [Counter-Strike Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkUuABNnTC0), and even [Team Fortress 2](http://www.schnittberichte.com/schnittbericht.php?ID=4539), the German version has ridiculous censorship.  However, according to a number of posts online *([1](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2911988), [2](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2966363), [3](http://steamcommunity.com/app/205100/discussions/0/864948300043427182/), [4](http://steamcommunity.com/app/205100/discussions/0/864949037823389396/))*, the German version of Dishonored **isn't** censored at all.  Most of these posts, though, were from before the game was actually released, and they're all anecdotal or second-hand.

So, **are there any confirmed sources that state whether the German version is or isn't censored?**

Comment: I like the german censored version of TF2 way better than the original one btw :P. It is just so funny to explode into toys.

Comment: woah. I did not know german censorship can be so strict. I am interested in seeing the TF2 haha.

Comment: FYI, Steam shows you a big orange warning if you are going to buy a censored version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not censored, the version is the same worldwide.

Source:

http://www.schnittberichte.com/svds.php?Page=Inhaltsangabe&ID=9045

http://www.schnittberichte.com/news.php?ID=3810

Comment: Hmm, this seems consistent with [Amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de/Dishonored-Maske-Zorns-100-Uncut/dp/B007IZ4268), which labels Dishonored as "100% Uncut".  Thanks!